# Try Catch Not working with async webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying to catch an exception in a delegating handler.

In my WebApiConfig.cs I have:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TestHandler1());
```

I have a delegating handler of

```
public class TestHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

I have a controller of

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The catch in the delegating handler is not being caught. Why not?

Comment: you need to have an `await` inside your `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()` (maybe a call to another async method)

Comment: In my actual code I do have it calling await service.DoStuff(), but it when that throws an exception the delegating handler isnt catching the error. This example was just simpler. Its just simulating an exception being thrown but not caught.

Comment: I am bit confuse as you said that exception is not caught. It is caught and that is why you see response 500. Do you see another response header ? You are right that it is not caught in your TestHandler1 because it is handle much before that convert into 500 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but in case it is to have a standard block to catch and handle exceptions, then check out the following links:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

http://blog.karbyn.com/index.php/handling-errors-in-web-api-using-exception-filters-and-exception-handlers/

In this case we are creating the Exception filter attribute and adding that at required level `action, controller, global` and this would get invoked in case of exception.

Also check the following link as it does the custom delegating handler, which are you are trying to use to exception handling

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling

Comment: Decided to use a ExceptionFilterAttribute and that works. After reading the link on web api exception handling it states that you cant try catch around the await base.SendAsync like I was trying. Thanks.